# Какой экзамен Битрикса сдавать для увеличения шанса устроится на работу программистом Битрикс?

Tags: php, битрикс

У Битрикса есть два экзамена:

1. «№1 - Интеграция дизайна и настройка платформы» - 999 р.
2. «№2 - Основные технологии и расширение типовых возможностей системы» - 1 999 р.

> https://academy.1c-bitrix.ru/personal/sertification/

Какой из них стоит сдать для увеличения шанса устройства на работу программистом Битрикс?

На какую зарплату можно рассчитывать?

Comment: Зарплаты у компаний разные. Все зависит от вашего опыта.
Экзамены не так важны, как опыт :)
Я не сдавал ни один из них, в итоге в компании больше года и получаю от 60к

Comment: возьмут на работу и без этого, и без опыта могут взять всё зависит от того на что претендуете (должность/зарплата). Но фирме (может не всем) выгодно если будет сертификат, они добавят себе что у них на +1 больше сертифицированных работников (и фирма среди партнёров битрикса будет повыше). Такой шаг по идеи увеличивает вашу стоимость как сотрудника (ну вряд ли совсем без опыта можно сдать платный сертификат, т.к. строже не как на бесплатных сертификатах где просто тест (и можно гуглить)). Попробуйте сдать если нет можно и без сертификата устроиться. (слышал что некоторые и с опытом не сдают)